# Time complexity of Prolog better than naive brute force?

Tags: c, prolog, scheme

Is the time complexity of solving anything in (the best) Prolog better than a naive brute force backtracking implementation?

I say the language Prolog generally... I'm wondering if there is some well known algorithm for this, that would for example make 'doing Prolog' using call/cc backtracking in Scheme a poor choice.

EDIT: by "solving anything" I mean all Prolog programs. The "question in a question": I'm wondering about language design: if full continuations have any practical utility over partial continuations (the main advantages being Prolog-esque, but which aren't serious if they can't compete on time complexity with Prolog), and also if another language could completely absorb Prolog or if there are optimizations made possible by restricting programs to a Prolog form (analogous to the optimization possible in Fortran over C).

EDIT: by time complexity I meant big O, i.e. pruning that wouldn't be possible emulating Prolog naively in a general language.

Comment: what do you mean with *solving* anything?

Comment: It is unclear to me which complexity you are referring to... That said, Prolog implementations typically have *very low* overhead for reclaiming memory upon backtracking (compared to Scheme call/cc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A naive brute force search will *remain* a naive brute force search when it is  *literally* translated to Prolog.

That's OK: Plain Prolog is very well suited for describing and running brute force searches. Still, you will likely not be able to beat a hand-optimized low-level version of any brute force search with a brute force search written in Prolog. On the other hand, Prolog is so easy and convenient to type that you will likely soon find better search strategies with a bit of prototyping, and these other strategies will often easily beat *any* brute force implementation by a huge margin. And even when translated naively, Prolog is pretty good at backtracking and does it efficiently within some (smaller or larger, depending on the Prolog implementation you use) factor of lower-level code.

However, the key advantage that Prolog has over many other languages when describing search problems are **constraints**: Due to so-called constraint *propagation*, the search space can often be pruned *significantly* and *automatically*. No special provisions are necessary on your part: The constraint solver will do it for you.

The promise of constraints, and that promise has to a large extent turned into reality, is that (1) you state the requirements and (2) the Prolog engine finds the solution for you. Check out [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for one very important instance of this scheme.

I therefore suggest the question: *In any language, how easy is it to convert a naive brute force search into a more informed search strategy?* After all, this is how the really significant improvements typically become possible.

In Prolog, the answer is often: **Very easy**. In most other languages, not so much.

Answer (score 3):

Given you ask for *solving anything*, there are definitely problems that are solved by Prolog in linear time. For instance the following `append/3` predicate:

```
append([H|A],B,[H|R]) :-
    append(A,B,R).
append([],L,L).
```

Now since at each step, there is only one candidate predicate, there is no branching, an hereby no exponential time complexity. The predicate runs linear in the length of the first list.

Furthermore one can allow *tabling* in Prolog which can result in some kind of dynamic programming which can turning brute force backtracking algorithms sometimes in fast algorithms.

Comment: You can get a lot of overhead with `append/3` for a query like `append([VeryBigTerm1,...],[],[BT1,...])` So it's not only the length but to a certain degree the terms contained in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The question within your question seems to be, if I write Prolog-like code in Scheme, is it going to perform worse than if I write Prolog in Prolog?

There's no straightforward answer. The truth is that the part of your problem that maps nicely onto Prolog will probably perform worse than it would in Prolog. Why? Because Prolog's intrinsics are all written in Prolog where your intrinsics are all written in Scheme. As @CommuSoft points out with `append/3`, the Prolog implementation of the intrinsic functions are able to leverage Prolog's strengths. You're going to be fighting an uphill battle in these parts. Plus, the Prolog implementations we have are old enough to have spent decades working to improve the performance of unification, because that's the interesting area here.

At the same time, most substantial Prolog programs eventually wind up with some procedural bits. Those bits are probably not competitive with C or Scheme, because they're not as fun to optimize and whatever research there was to be done on this was happening in Scheme and ML instead. So you will win in those areas.

As a Scheme user, I would think that you would find it more profitable to write programs in the Scheme style: functional, with a dash of macros to give it a declarative feel. If you have a problem that is embarrassingly good for Prolog, you can always throw [miniKanren](http://minikanren.org/) at it, but keep it cordoned off from the rest of your program. Let your language be your language.

I disagree with @ahuemmer about C versus Prolog only because labor is finite and programs have many aspects besides performance. The authorship costs of C are a lot higher, so you will commit harder to poorer strategies and wind up with less flexible code. Even if you confine your problem space to something small and well-defined, the Prolog programmer will have more time to experiment and discover a better solution, possibly with better time-complexity. If we are talking about unlimited amounts of labor, the C version will probably outperform the first Prolog version. But you have to consider all the dimensions.

In general I think it's more important to fit the programmer to the language than the language to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Prolog (without the "cut" operator, or imperative features) excels in one regard: For a certain class of problems, it is a "complete refutation procedure". If the problem has no solution, the Prolog program will terminate and announce the absence of solutions. On the other hand, if the problem does have solutions, the program may find none or some or all, and fail to terminate.

If you use imperative features or cuts, all bets are off.

Prolog can sometimes handle problems with infinitely many answers, if the answers have the right kind of pattern.

Comment: Almost: "if the problem has no solution", Prolog does not necessarily terminate.

Comment: Note that I wrote "for a certain class of problems." Look up "finite Herbrand model."

Comment: If you read your statement like that, then you should include also cuts since they perfectly work for "a certain class of problems" too. Or rather for " a certain class of programs"

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it depends on the problem. If it is really solvable only via brute force and backtracking, I don't think that (even an idealized "*best*") Prolog would be faster than e. g. a well-written C program.

On the other hand, if you have that kind of problem for the solution of which Prolog can use its database and deductive approach (so, not neccessarily brute force backtracking), it might have a better performance than another brute force backtracking program.

In the end, every programming language ends up creating machine code that runs on your CPU to (hopefully) solve your problem. The same machine code can also be produced by other languages or more or less directly by the programmer. So, at all, Prolog is a good way to solve some kind of problems, but it need not be the best / fastest / only alternative.